# Magento how to disable product page

Tags: magento, view, product

I need to disable the product page within Magento. So even if someone tried to visit the page it would give a 404.

Any ideas how I would go about that?

Thank you

** Edit ** I should point out that I still need the product to be visible on the list page etc I just don't want customers to be able to visit the products page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the product as disabled in Magento Admin panel. (Product status attribute)

UPD: You should overwrite the `viewAction` method from the `Mage_Catalog_ProductController`. The body of this method should consist of only one string: `$this->_forward('noRoute'); return;`

Comment: Thanks. But I need the product to be visible as I still need it to show on the list page etc (customers will add to cart directly from the list page).

Comment: Then you should overwrite the viewAction method from the Mage_Catalog_ProdcutController. And the body of this method should consists only of one string: `$this->_forward('noRoute'); return;
`

Comment: ahh ok thanks! I'll give that a go. Can you provide that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks